# Continuous Delivery / Deployment and Process Controls

Tags: jira, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

From a "process controls" POV, in a continuous delivery/deployment context, how important is it to mandate that source control commits are associated with an Agile PM (or ticketing tool) "work-item?"  Here "work-item" means any of: user story, task, defect, bug, etc.

The end-goal is to ensure that developers are not placing new features into production that were not derived from the product owner.  Obviously code reviews are a critical part of a proper process-controls story, but having a code review presumes the reviewer can look at the associated statement of work (e.g. user story) to ensure the code changes reflect the requested work.

Herein lies the issue.

### Context

I've always *assumed* to have a workflow where work-tickets are associated with commits, such as with Jira, but now I'm working with a corporation whose PM tool is incapable of associating work-items or defect-tickets with source commits.

With this client, I'm also seeing a catch-22.  First, I'm told by representatives of the PMO that such ticket-to-commit associations are not needed.  Second, the engineering org paid for an outside consultancy to audit and flag major process flaws.  The #1 flaw that was identified was the inability for management to know if developer commits have any bearing on authorized work.

From my POV, I think the PMO needs to realize that they are the "tail wagging the dog" and that they need to embrace tooling changes or special integrations to overcome this problem (not to mention more maturity with Agile philosophy).

However, perhaps **I'm the one** who simply is over-concerned about the ticket-to-commit associations, and perhaps there is another way to achieve effective process controls without that particular mechanism?

Comment: Sounds to me like you are trying to solve a people problem as if it was a technical problem.

Comment: @Robert.  Yes, I reasonably presume this is a people problem - but I want to challenge my own presumption by asking this question.  If nobody agrees that a tool-based traceability mechanism is important, then I know the people issue is actually with *me*. :)

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with regulated industries, such as health care or governing bodies, full traceability from scope to code is a requirement. I once had to perform an audit to validate that every line of code correlates to a line in the [SRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_requirements_specification) for FDA approval, although generally it's enough to demonstrate that there **exists** a method of traceability (such as a branch in github that is named to match a task / story in JIRA and code integration is enabled).

If you're not in a regulated industry, requirement-to-code traceability is not a requirement... but it is still immensely helpful. The advantages include, and are not limited to:

- Full transparency to everyone on the team, tech or not. The amount of confidence that this evokes is amazing, and the amount of chatter it reduces.
- Reports to identify what theme in the requirements are causing the greatest amount of code churn, because there's a heavy cost to that.
- Identifying features affected by a PR. This is immensely helpful when a release is planned, some aspects of the release are unattainable or buggy, a lot of the code has already been merged, and the team needs to isolate what to release and what not to.
- Confirmation of an opinionated truth by remove the opinion: "I'm sure I did it... let's double check... yup! (or oops, let's rectify that!)". This helps deter [CYA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_your_ass) behavior, which is drain on morale and negatively influences efficiency.
- Simple implementation with existing mainstream toolsets (JIRA, Trello, Asana, Freshdesk for tickets... Github, Bitbucket for repo and tickets... Zapier, IFTTT for integrations across systems that lack built-in integrations)

For every team I have ever managed or established (as dev manager, PMO, product manager, consultant or founder), it has been my explicit expectation that every line of code can be traced to the requirement for the reasons listed above. I advocate implementing this using the branch-per-topic pattern in git (Github or Bitbucket), where the branch is prefixed by the JIRA task/story/bug (eg. XYZ-2443-fix-that-bug) so that JIRA's integration automatically displays a link of the branch to the issue.

*Of course, this is not the only way, but it is my preferred process at this time and is meant to illustrate a concrete example.*